# Visual Studio 2022: is it possible to do a git merge without auto commit?

Tags: merge, git-merge, visual-studio-2022

In VS 2019, using the "legacy" git experience, when I want to do a merge there is an option "commit changes after merging". I usually de-check it. I can't find this option in VS2022. Is there a way to restore it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You can uncheck "Commit changes after merge by default" from Tools -> Options ->  Source Control -> Git Global Settings
[image]